# use geocoder gem to store address of one model search with address of the other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I have 2 models one for customer and one for vendor, I'm trying do make a site that when customer sign in, they can search using their ip address and search for near by location, the result will be some vendor with nearby address. So far, I plan to use geocoder and gmap4rails gem. I'm still not sure how I would store the vendors address using geocoder so that when the customer search, the correct result will be presented. Can some one give suggestion on how to design this feature?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I haven't try anything actually, so Far I have only able to sign customer and vendor up and update their account information, I'm not sure what step i should do next in order to set up the feature mentioned above. I just need some kind of a general design for the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just looking for a "design" and not code, I can just outline the broad steps:

ip form submitted =>
lookup geodata for local businesses =>
store geodata in "vendor" model =>

The only non-standard rails part of this is the geo-lookup.

There are multiple ways to do this, most certainly using some external API. I don't think the `geocoder` or `gmap4rails` gems have this functionality.

While you're probably using `gmap4rails` for your view layer, I'm not sure you'll need the `geocoder` gem if you're using a different service to perform the vendors lookup. This external service might accomplish the same thing.

As for which external service to use: I'd look at Yelp or one of Google's APIs.

---

In response to your comment:

When a user logs in, you'll probably want to set a `session` cookie for them.

There is no reason to have the ip form "belong to" any user. When the form is submitted, you'd be able to look up the current signed in user from the controller action which is hit when the form is submitted.

If you store vendor data in your database, you can then present the data in the view.

If these concepts are new to you, I'd recommend going through a detailed tutorial of Rails.

Comment: so the ip form belong to customer account and when a customer sign in, he/she can search for list of vendors with near by address?

Comment: @KhoaVo thanks for accepting my answer, but there's no need to do  it so soon after posting. You might get more responses if you leave it unaccepted for a little while.